# Can we run php application in a LAN?

Tags: installation, lan

I have to install php application in a one computer and access these application from  others computer in a LAN. is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes. It is possible.**

Install PHP and configure the PHP application on one computer on the LAN. Let's call this machine `myserver.local`. Then test out the application on the same workstation to make sure it's working fine. You'd probably be using a URL like this:

```
http://localhost/appname/index.php
```

Once you're sure that it works fine, then you can use the following to access the application from the other computers in the LAN:

```
http://myserver.local/appname/index.php
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

If the computer you are hosting the php application is a part of the intranet then all you have to do is send the application link or the ip to others and they can access the application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can,

You can use the server IP Address(IP of machine where server software's are installed) to access the content on remote machine.